# Building Page Block Tables with Dynamic Component with Input fields causes errors

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-vf-component

I am building a form using dynamic components. I am using Dynamic components due to the fact the data I am displaying will need an unknown number of tables and tabs.

I am using wrapper classes.  In the sample class below, wrapperClass2 has a list of wrapperclass1.

I am running into issues when using InputText and InputCheckbox.  I keep getting the error

**Unknown property 'BytecodeApexObject.testCheckbox'
Error is in expression '{!qlx.testCheckbox}' in component  in page testpage**

Below is a sample of code which shows the basics of what I am trying to do.

**VisualForce Page**

```
<apex:page id="myPage" Controller="TestPage">  
    <apex:form id="myForm">
      <apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!tabbedView}" /> 
   </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

**Controller Class**

```
public with sharing class TestPage {

    public List<wrapperClass2> myList{get;set;}
    public Integer myCount{get;set;}

    class wrapperClass1{
        public Boolean testCheckbox{get;set;}
        public string testText{get;set;}        

        public wrapperClass1(){
            this.testCheckbox = false;
            this.testText = 'Test';
        }
    }

    class wrapperClass2{
        public List<wrapperClass1> innerList{get;set;}

        public wrapperClass2(){
            innerList = new List<wrapperClass1>();
            for(integer i = 0; i<10; i++){
                wrapperClass1 temp = new wrapperClass1();
                temp.testText = 'MyTest';
                innerList.Add(temp);

            }
        }
    }

    public List<wrapperClass2> getList(){
        if(myList == null)
        {
            myList = new List<wrapperClass2>();
            wrapperClass2 myClass = new wrapperClass2();
            myList.add(myClass);

        }
        return myList;
    }

    //  Comman Button Action.  Increases Count
    public void doSomething(){
        if(myCount == null)
            myCount=0;
        myCount++;
    }

    public Component.Apex.TabPanel getTabbedView()
    {
        Component.Apex.TabPanel panel = new Component.Apex.TabPanel(switchtype='client', Title='Test Tabs');

        if(myList == null)
            getList();
        for(wrapperClass2 a: myList)
        {
            Component.Apex.Tab theTab = new Component.Apex.Tab();
            thetab.label = 'First Tab';
            panel.childComponents.Add(theTab);

            Component.Apex.PageBlock theBlock = new Component.Apex.PageBlock();
            theBlock.Title = 'First Block';
            theTab.ChildComponents.Add(theBlock);

            Component.Apex.PageBlockButtons thePageButtons = new Component.Apex.PageBlockButtons();
            thePageButtons.Location='top';          
            Component.Apex.CommandButton theCommandButton = new Component.Apex.CommandButton();
            Set<String> render = new set<String>();
            render.add('theBlock');
            theCommandButton.rerender=render;
            theCommandButton.Value='Update';
            thePageButtons.childComponents.Add(theCommandButton);
            theBlock.ChildComponents.Add(thePageButtons);

            Component.Apex.PageBlockSection theSection = new Component.Apex.PageBlockSection();
            theSection.Title = 'Test Section';
            theSection.Columns = 1;
            theBlock.ChildComponents.Add(theSection);

            Component.Apex.PageBlockTable theTable = new Component.Apex.PageBlockTable();   
            theTable.value = a.innerList;
            theTable.var = 'thisList';
            theSection.ChildComponents.Add(theTable);

            Component.Apex.Column theTextColumn = new Component.Apex.Column();
            theTextColumn.HeaderValue = 'Test Text Entry';
            Component.Apex.InputText newQuantityField = new Component.Apex.InputText();
            newQuantityField.Style = 'width: 50px;';

            newQuantityField.Expressions.Value='{!thisList.testText}';
            theTextColumn.ChildComponents.Add(newQuantityField);
            theTable.childcomponents.add(theTextColumn);

            Component.Apex.Column theCheckboxColumn = new Component.Apex.Column();
            theCheckboxColumn.HeaderValue = 'Test Checkbox';
            Component.Apex.InputCheckBox checkboxField = new Component.Apex.InputCheckBox(); 

            checkboxField.expressions.Value = '{!thisList.testCheckbox}';
            theCheckboxColumn.ChildComponents.Add(checkboxField);
            theTable.childcomponents.add(theCheckboxColumn);

        }
        return Panel;

    }

}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Sam, Can you please explain little more ? Where you are getting error, in Component Controller ? Can you post complete code ?

Comment: Hi Jitendra.  I am getting the error when the page loads.  The two lines that seem to be causing the issue is when I bind the InputText and InputCheckbox to the fields in the wrapped class.  Essentially  Component.Apex.InputText textField = new Component.Apex.InputText();  textField.Expressions.Value='{!thisList.testText}';

Comment: The above code should be a complete example.  The actual project is quite large but the above code shows the issue I am running into